# Creating a duplicate with changed value, TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a price list that look like this:

```
ProductName Year Month Price 

name_1      2020   1   5,34 
name_1      2020   2   5,34 
name_1      2020   3   5,34
name_1      2020   4   5,34
name_1      2020   5   5,34
name_1      2020   6   5,34
           ...
```

And it goes like this till month 12. I wanted to create a duplicate so that there is also year 2021. I did it like this:

```
SELECT * INTO [New_Price_List] FROM [Price_List] WHERE [Year]='2020';
UPDATE [New_Price_List] SET Year='2021';
INSERT INTO [Price_List] SELECT * FROM [New_Price_List];
```

It would have worked, however, there are some products that don't have first few months and it doesn't work for them:

```
ProductName Year Month Price

name_2      2020   4   5,39
name_2      2020   5   5,39
name_2      2020   6   5,39
           ...
```

Is there some easy way to create these first months(or the whole product) so that every product has rows with months from 1 to 12? Anything works

Comment: What if the price changed half way through the year? What price should be used then?

Comment: It doesn't matter, since the price is changed later with another code. So the price can even be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that the price from the *last* month in 2020 should be used, not the prices duplicate, as otherwise price changes would be copied across too; which I doubt is wanted. For example if a product started at `5.34` in January and when to `5.49` in May, you wouldn't want it going back to to `5.34` in January 2021.

Therefore I would get the latest values, and then make all 12 rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ProductName, [Year], [Month], Price)
SELECT YT.ProductName,
       YT.[Year] + 1,
       V.[Month],
       YT.Price
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))V([Month])
WHERE YT.[Year] = 2020
  AND YT.[Month] = 12;
```